# I want to loop through Woocommerce Product Catogories and show them in dropdown

Tags: terms, dropdown

I want to loop through **Woocommerce Product Catogories** and show them in **dropdown**. I have tried almost every piece of code available on internet but seems that they are not working for me. I'm very new in wordpress. Can anyone help me out? Currently i'm using this code but it's not returning anything.

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$orderby = 'name';
$show_count = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$pad_counts = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
$hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
$title = '';
$empty = 0;

$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'show_count' => $show_count,
    'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
    'title_li' => $title,
    'hide_empty' => $empty
);
$all_categories = get_categories($args);
foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if ($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;
        echo '<br /><a href="' . get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') . '">' . $cat->name . '</a>';
        ?>
        <?php

        $args2 = array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'child_of' => 0,
            'parent' => $category_id,
            'orderby' => $orderby,
            'show_count' => $show_count,
            'pad_counts' => $pad_counts,
            'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
            'title_li' => $title,
            'hide_empty' => $empty
        );
        $sub_cats = get_categories($args2);
        if ($sub_cats) {
            foreach ($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                echo $sub_category->name;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The `title_li` element used in your args list seems invalid. Refer below link for reference:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

Answer (score 2):

[`wp_dropdown_categories()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) does exactly that. Don't let the name confuse you, it is not just meant for the built-in taxonomy `category`. Simply set the `taxonomy` parameter to the value of your custom taxonomy. Also work through the list of parameters and set as necessary.

Just a small note on your code, avoid passing just term IDs to `get_term_link()`, it makes the function expensive as it needs to query the db to get the term object. You already have the term object, so simply pass the complete object to `get_term_link()`.